# shearing force distribution in a trapezoid

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I need help figuring the distribution of a horizontal shearing force in an elastic solid trapezoid. When force $F_1$ is applied to all the top surface of the trapezoid, at equilibrium, is the force in all horizontal layers of the solid the same? That is $F_1=F_2=F_3=F_4$? Or is the shear stress the same and the force varies between layers?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the main trapezoid, a cantilever column( assuming it is thin enough to be subject of plane shear, not a solid) with load F applied to the top.

We know that $ \ \Sigma F_x =0 $

This means if we consider the free body diagram of the column at any horizontal level including the base and the level shown in your diagram, shear, V is constant and is always:

V = -F1.

However the shear flow, q is not the same and shear stress increases as the length of the base of trapezoid in the free body diagram decrease. e.g. if the length of the base is half of the length on top the shear flow q is two times the shear flow of the top.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what shear flow is, and how does it differ from shear stress. I understand that since V (or F) is the same in all layer of the trapezoid, then the shear stress is inversely proportional to the area. how the parameter shear flow aid in understanding, I am not sure. what matters to me the most is the bottom line. please confirm if its correct to say that in each layer ∑Fx =0. therefore the same F acts on all layer, and stress  vary inversely with change in area. thank you

Comment: @Yehuda Raveh, yes, right. Because there is only one horizontal force F1 applied on top, the shear force is constant at any level and is inversely proportional to the area at that level. At least for thin planes. When the thickness of plane is bigger than 0.1 of the width it becomes more complicated.

Comment: I am doing an integral of total displacement of annular elastic body where the outer layer rotates relative to the fixated inner layer . So the thickness is infinitesimal. Could you please suggest a book or article that I can use as a reference?

Comment: I am a physician not a physicist or engineer so I seek help

Comment: @YehudaRaveh Here is a link to tapered wood beam deflection under the shear, of course, you need to add to that moment deflection as well.-- If you are not an engineer you benefit little from this, but it doesn't hurt to check.  https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/fplrp/fplrp34.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Newton's Second Law of Motion tells us that the force applied to an object is equal to the product of said object's mass and its acceleration.

$$F=ma$$

So, assuming that your trapezoid (both "halves" of it) remain static (that is, with $a=0$), then the *net force* applied on the trapezoid must also be zero. In this case, we can therefore state that the sum of all the horizontal forces must be equal to zero:

$$\sum F_x = F_1 - F_2 + F_3 - F_4 = 0$$

(the minus signs for $F_2$ and $F_4$ are because of the orientation you gave those forces in your question).

The forces all being equal would satisfy that equation, but so would an infinitely many other configurations (i.e. $F_1 = F_2 + F_4$ and $F_3 = 0$).

However, you've split your trapezoid into two halves. I assume this means it's actually two trapezoids, one resting upon the other, and that both are static ($a=0$). In this case, we can apply the same equation to each individual trapezoid, which gives us

$$\begin{align}
\sum F_x &= F_1 - F_2 = 0 \\
\sum F_x &= F_3 - F_4 = 0
\end{align}$$

This is obviously solvable, with $F_1 = F_2$ and $F_3 = F_4$. However, we still can't tell whether the two pairs are equal to each other (that is, whether $F_1 = F_3$).

For that, we can rely on Newton's Third Law, which states that every action produces an equal and opposite reaction. Looking at $F_2$ and $F_3$, that's clearly what we're looking at: the action and reaction along the interface between the two trapezoids. So we can obviously state that $F_2 = F_3$, which combined with the previous deduction gives us

$$F_1 = F_2 = F_3 = F_4$$

So the forces are all equal. Since the areas upon which these forces are acting are different, this means the shear stresses will be different.

Note that, as is, your trapezoid would actually rotate due to the couple formed by $F_1$ and $F_4$, though that seems to be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: excellent. exactly what I thought.

Comment: Could you please suggest a book or article that I can use as a reference?

Comment: @YehudaRaveh: The arguments I used here are entirely based on Newton's Laws of Motion, which are some of the foundational concepts in physics, so honestly any basic (middle/high-school level) textbook should be enough.

Comment: @YehudaRaveh: Also, if you've found any of the answers given to your question useful, please make sure to choose one to mark as accepted (the checkmark to the left of each answer).